# 301 Redirecting pages with specific subpage in URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am woundering if there is a way to redirect all pages with specific parent page in URL

Basically  I have a following duplicates of pages :

> www.website/product-category-2/x-category

as well as

> www.website/product-category/x-category

Is there a way to create a redirect that will push all the pages from product-category-2 to product-category?

So the redirect will look like this:

> www.website/product-category-2/* -> www.website/product-category/*

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^product-category-2/(.*) /product-category/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It will redirect `www.website/product-category-2/*` to `www.website/product-category/*`

Comment: As in it wasn't redirected at all?

Comment: Yeat. hothing at all. I have it in my wordpress htaccess file which looks like this :
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /website/main/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /website/main/index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^product-category-2/(.*) /product-category/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Does the product show if you enter `www.website.com/product-category/someproduct`?

Comment: Yes, but those are the same products as product-category-2. Mess!

Comment: Can you try a hard refresh/try another browser?

Comment: Done that. Nothing happened. No idea

Comment: The url for the product, is it `www.website.com/product-category/someproduct` or `www.website.com/website/main/product-category/someproduct`?